# JSON.parse error on valid JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

With this code in the console:

```
> typeof(body)
   "string"

> body
   "{author:"asd"}"

> JSON.parse(body);
VM2898:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Why is the parse of the string to JSON is failing? Seems valid to me...

Comment: All property names have to be quoted in JSON.

Comment: Because it is not valid [JSON](http://json.org). A valid JSON looks like `{"author":"asd"}` (property names are always enclosed in double quotes).

Comment: ok well thanks, some online parsers/validators seem to accept property names without quotes

Comment: Valid JavaScript != Valid JSON. Submit a bug report for parsers that parsed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not a valid JSON. Try this:

```js
var body = '{"author":"asd"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(body));
```